# Загрузка картинки из кэша

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как загрузить картинку из кэша, а не по определённому пути браузера? При помощи js или jquery.

```
var images = ['images/1.png', 'images/2.png'];
$.each(images, function (index, value) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = value;
});
```

Предположим, вот я занёс 2 картинки в кэш (проверено - занеслись). Лежат в кеше, ждут дела. Теперь у меня есть img с классом result, которому нужно подгрузить картинку из кэша

```
$('.result3').attr("src", 'images/1.png');
```

Так грузит не из кэша, а по прямому пути =((, а как выполнить загрузку из кэша?

Comment: 99.9999% у вас бесконечный цикл или переполнение стека

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятнее всего что никак, браузер сам отдает откуда ему нужно.

Comment: Тогда почему, когда я делаю цикл на смену картинок ( в js), т.е. поочерёдно присваиваю `$('.result3').attr("src", 'images/1.png');` а затем `$('.result3').attr("src", 'images/2.png');` через некоторое время бразер виснет, пока не нажмешь ctrl+f5 или не закроешь откроешь заново страницу? Значит, кэш таки перегружается чем-то.

Comment: Может проблема в том, что забивается кэш jsфайла из-за бесконечного цикла, может какой memori limit есть, как в php.

Comment: Именно так и есть!